# How do I access Windows eventlog of a Docker container

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

How do I access the Windows Event Log of a Microsoft Docker container from the host?

I have a docker container under Windows Server 2016.

The container is based on image: microsoft/iis

I can get the ip address of the container with:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" my-running-site
```

How can I connect to it via the Event Viewer on the windows host?

Comment: good question! of course you can powershell into your container and use `get-eventlog` as expected, but connecting from the host to the container would mean that the container is listening to external request for the eventlog. If you check your container for listening ports there is only port 135 (RPC) listening, which MAY be the right. Next step is exposing that port to the outside with `docker run -p 135:135...` but during my try it did not work... how about posting that question in the docker or container forums or GitHub?

Comment: I'm not sure that the eventlog is the way to go with logging inside of containers. Whilst it's a traditional tool in windows, the lightweight nature of containers makes redirecting to stdout and stderr better candidates for logging for containers. This has further benefits such as delegating log analysis to tools such logstash and elasticsearch. It's then easier to query multiple containers and store the logs centrally. Also redirecting to stdout and stderr allows you to easily run docker logs ... from the command line of your host to easily obtain logs.

Comment: I can't always control what gets logged to where. If I open port 135 I get 'Access Denied (5)'.

Comment: My current understanding of your question is: whether it is possible to let an application (such as IIS) running inside a container log events into Windows Event Log, and use Windows Event Viewer from the host to view those events. Am I understanding correctly? I'm also interested to know the answer.

Comment: Me too. I'm also curious how can we make it? What about run a process keep writing logs to the the data folder, and the host can access that?

Comment: @GregPagendam-Turner Have you received any solution or fixed the problem? I have tried many different approaches but **cannot copy the log files to my local drive**

Answer (score 21):

Create a **powershell session** for the container

```
docker exec -it  <container_id> powershell
```

Then from the container, get the **latest event logs**

```
Get-Eventlog -newest 20 application
```

Above command will help you to find the index,

```
(Get-Eventlog -index xxx application).message
```

Comment: Not worked amigo. Gives "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "powershell": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown"

Comment: Do you have PowerShell installed in the container. If not, try with bash or cmd

Comment: I followed the steps above and I also fix the problem by installing powershell. However, I cannot copy log.json file from Docker contained to my local drive on Windows. I followed this approach. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/383441

Comment: So, if it is possible to copy it, why cannot I copy and run these commands? I have a similar problem like on the following page. You may post your answer to it as I follow it. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66055244/docker-error-no-such-containerpath-while-trying-to-copy-to-local-drive?noredirect=1#comment116814489_66055244

Comment: Have you received any solution or fixed the problem? I have tried many different approaches but **cannot copy the log files to my local drive**

Answer (score 5):

On PWSH (Powershell Core):

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Application
```

Answer (score 4):

The Docker Engine logs to the Windows 'Application' event log, rather than to a file. These logs can easily be read, sorted, and filtered using Windows PowerShell

For example, this will show the Docker Engine logs from the last 5 minutes starting with the oldest.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source Docker -After (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5) | Sort-Object Time
```

Comment: I don't think this is a solution, as you only get the source of Docker, not the process running inside the container.

Comment: Yeah, those aren't IIS logs. This is way simpler in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [evtail.exe](https://github.com/christian-korneck/evtail) to tail the Windows Event Log inside a Docker Windows Container. It doesn't require Powershell, so even works on Nano Server (which doesn't include Powershell).