# VB.NET web application project docker deployment 403 Error(VS 2019)

Tags: vb.net, docker, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to deploy vb.net web application project (.NET Framework) using Docker option of Visual Studio 2019 and have been running into "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied." error.
However, I am able to run the project by using IIS option.
I am new to both VB.Net and Docker. Please let me know if more information is required to answer this question.

IIS Logs ("[How do I access Windows eventlog of a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215471/how-do-i-access-windows-eventlog-of-a-docker-container)") attached as image here:[IIS Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaIrc.png)

Answer (score 1):

I am putting this answer here for any beginner who may struggle with this:
On running from Visual Studio 2019, using "Docker" option, I was getting an IP on the browser with an error "403-Forbidden". However, when I appended the webform.aspx to it, the error resolved.
So Instead of checking output at 172.24.152.32, I was supposed to view the output at 172.24.152.32/webform.aspx or localhost:52345/webform.aspx.

Comment: can you please tell me which docker image are you using to run vb.net base applications?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put a default document into the container. A simple index.html or default.html should do.