# Docker Error: No such container:path.. while trying to copy to local drive

Tags: docker

I have tried to copy a json file from a Docker container to a local drive path on Windows machine as shown below:

```
docker cp <my-container-name>:/var/lib/docker/containers/123abc-json.log  C:\\log
docker cp <my-container-name>:/var/lib/docker/containers/123abc-json.log  C:\\log\123abc-json.log

I also tried these commands using container_id:


docker cp <my-container-ID>:/var/lib/docker/containers/123abc-json.log  C:\\log
docker cp <my-container-ID>:/var/lib/docker/containers/123abc-json.log  C:\\log\123abc-json.log
```

But I get "*Error: No such container:path: :/var/lib/docker/containers/123abc/123abc-json.log*" error. So, what is the problem?

Comment: What's the output of `docker exec <my-container-ID> ls /var/lib/docker/containers`?

Comment: @BahmanMovaqar *"cannot access '/var/lib/docker/containers': No such file or directory"*.

Comment: Well, that means the path you are trying to copy from does not exist in the container.

Comment: But when ı run `docker inspect <container_id>` I get the `LogPath` value as `"LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/144.../144...-json.log"`. So, what is this meaning? If there such a directory, why it shows this?

Comment: Any how can I access and copy log.json file from Docker container to my local drive?

Comment: That is the path to the container log file on the host (not the container.) The correct way to access the logs of a container is via `docker logs`.

Comment: Yes, I could access via `docker logs`, but what if I want to access that log.json file and copy it to my local drive? why is it not possible?

Comment: And is there a proper way to monitor logs to display them in format and better way than using `docker logs` command?

Comment: @BahmanMovaqar Any help please?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is very different from the question. Can you edit the question and the title and clearly explain what you want to achieve and what you have done so far? You certainly will get better advice.

Comment: @BahmanM As indicated in the questions: **"I have tried to copy a json file from a Docker container to a local drive path on Windows machine"**.

Comment: So, **I tried to apply the steps as mentioned on**: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/383441